# Where should I ask questions about ASO (App Store Optimization)?

Tags: discussion

I would like to know what community fits better to ask a question about ASO (App Store Optimization), which is roughly the equivalent of SEO, but for Apple's App Store.

I tried to ask [a question on this topic on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58676013/aso-how-to-properly-use-long-tail-keywords-with-app-store)  a few days ago, but the only answer I got was that it was off topic, and that it should be closed.

Comment: If it's SEO I'd suggest https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seo **but check their guidelines FIRST**.

Comment: @Paulie_D I don't think that's the right site, since ASO is not a task webmasters do. While ASO is similar to SEO, it's certainly not the same. ASO is not directly related to websites. I don't have a better suggestion, though, I think no SE sites fit.

Comment: Since you're asking about the Apple App Store specifically, it might be on topic for Ask Different. Review their guidelines here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Nowhere? Is nowhere a place? This shouldn’t even be a thing… It certainly isn’t on-topic for the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I think Apple Stack Echange fits better because even if ASO is a sort of SEO, the url contains “webmasters", which IMO ASO has nothing to do with. I’m afraid any ASO question would be rejected there because of this.